# SFMC - SMS Data Extension, having multiple of the same mobile numbers (different Subscriber Key) in the DE - only sends to ONE of the duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, duplicate-management, sms

EDIT: [Duplicates in sendable DE for MobileConnect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229376/duplicates-in-sendable-de-for-mobileconnect) is not a duplicate of my question.  I recognize that this is a limitation of SFMC and am inquiring about ***any known workarounds***.  The linked question does not inquire about any workarounds, in fact, it's basically just asking "why is this happening".  I know why it's happening.

Is there any way around this SFMC limitation?  I have a sendable data extension I'm using for SMS sending via Automation Studio.  The use cases involve potentially having the same mobile number in the data extension multiple times, with the expectation that that mobile number will receive XXX number of messages where they exist XXX times in the data extension.  See below - notice my cell number is in here twice, but with different subscriber keys.  When I invoke the automation to send this, I only receive a single SMS representing the TOP record, not both, as expected.  I figure this is standard out of the box functionality similar to "de-duplicating email subscribers".  Is there any way around this limitation, perhaps via a back end business rule setting?

[image]

Comment: On batch sends Mobile connect Dedupes by mobilenumber, you would need to break this into different sends

Comment: Also https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TkdQAE

Comment: @EazyE it doesn't... I saw that post as well, and I recognize this is a SFMC limitation.. my question is around any potential workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 below is an answer.

There are several ways to send SMS in a sort of "batch" process.

1. Automation Studio > Send SMS
2. Journey Builder > Send SMS

When you run this through Automation Studio, mobile numbers are de-duplicated automatically.  However, when I run this through Journey Builder (pointing to the audience DE), duplicates ARE in fact sent.